# Generate an R timeseries in C# for use with RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, time-series, r.net

I have some time series data in C#, i.e., measurement (a double) and a date in the form of a DateTime, currently as a `List<DateTime, double>`.
I am using the RDotNet package version 1.5 installed via NuGet.

How do I get my time series into R in order to create some plots and perform other calculations using the tools available there.

Here is some code from the RDotNet examples with which I can create a vector without DateTimes:

```
using RDotNet;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace RTimeSeries
{
  class RTimeSeriesTest
  {
    public static void createVector(double[] doublearray)
    {
      var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
      var rBinPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\i386";
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);
      using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
      {
        engine.Initialize();
        var myvector = engine.CreateNumericVector(doublearray);
        engine.SetSymbol("myvector", myvector);
      }
    }

    public static void test()
    {
      createVector(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to convert my C# time series to an R time series?
I am hoping for a `ts` object, if possible.

--

I am using R version 3.0.1 on Windows 64 bit. I installed this from the [binary windows installer](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).

--

I want to send data from google trends, such as about "nfl" as in [relative search interest for "NFL" in the US](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=nfl&geo=US&cmpt=q). Google trends delivers weekly data from 2004. I then want to somehow convert the series have a (more) constant variance, then estimate the seasonal part of the variations and as a result get the seasonal part and the remaining (including the trend) part.

In R directly I tried creating a time series like this:

```
nfl.ts<-ts(data=searches$Searches, frequency=52.1775, start=c(2004,1))
```

thus ignoring the dates from google and assuming a uniform distribution of observations.

One problem, that should perhaps be another question on another stackexchange site is how to handle fractional frequencies, as a whole number of weeks do not fit perfectly into one year. So the frequency of weeks in a year will vary a little, in particular for leap years. How should I handle this problem?

I then tried

```
plot(stl(nfl.ts,s.window="periodic"))
```

but the results do not look correct for at least a few of the time series.

Comment: Please make this reproducible.  There's a typo: `mxvector` should be `myvector`, but also you need `using System;`, `using RDotNet;`, a namespace and class, etc.  Also, it would be good to mention which version of RDotNet you're using.  Did you build from source?  Finally, what kind of timeseries do you want?  a `ts` object? something else?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I hope I corrected all of it.

Comment: Can you just do something like `engine.Evaluate("myts <- ts(myvector, start=c(2013, 1), end=c(2013, 10), frequency=12)");`?